# Why does x3103 have the value x1482 at the end

Tags: lc3

Edit: The original question is this

Suppose the following LC-3 program is loaded into memory starting at
location x30FF:

x30FF 1110 0010 0000 0001

x3100 0110 0100 0100 0010

x3101 1111 0000 0010 0101

x3102 0001 0100 0100 0001

x3103 0001 0100 1000 0010

If the program is executed, what is the value in R2 at the end of
execution?

x30FF    1110 0010 0000 0001  ; R1 <- PC' + 1      ; R1 <- x3101

x3100    0110 0100 0100 0010  ; R2 <- mem[R1 + 2]  ; R2 <- mem[x3103] = x1482

x3101    1111 0000 0010 0101  ; TRAP x25 = HALT

x3102    0001 0100 0100 0001  ; x1441

x3103    0001 0100 1000 0010  ; x1482

The question is what is the content of R2 at the end of the program

In this problem I understand everything until x3100

However I don't understand what mem[R1+2] means and how x3102 has x1441 in Register 2 and how x3103 has the value x1482.

As far I can tell, nothing is loaded into R2 at any point.

Where does x1441 and x1482 come from?

Can somebody explain how R2 has x1482 in it?

Answer (score 1):

Going over the machine language you posted.

The first instruction which is LEA R1, 1 will simply store PC + 1 into R1.  Since the PC will be x3100 at the time that instruction is executed x3101 is stored into R1.

The second instruction which is LDR R2, R1, 2 will take R1's value add 2 
 and then load from memory at the address formed from the previous computation and store it in R2.  R1's value is x3101, x3101 + 2 is x3103 so whatever is at address x3103 will be stored in R2.  Since you posted that x3103 contains x1482 that is what gets stored in R2.

The phrasing mem[R1+2] means to load from memory at the address computed by taking R1's value and adding 2 to it.

From your edit, yeah the x1441 and x1482 appear to just be data.